# how to count number of rows in related table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables in my database

articles
With the following fields

id  author     post_date   modification    title   section_id  views   featured    content     post_status

sections
With the following fields

- sec_id   description   slug    category

I have a function in my model to return all the sections

```
function get_all() {
            $q = $this->db->select('sec_id,category,slug,description')
                            ->from('sections')
                        ->order_by('category','asc');
            $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();
            return $ret;
        }
```

Am display this in a table

```
<div id="categories">

<div id="toolbar">
</div>

<table>
<thead class="table_header">
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" name="check_all" id="master_box" onclick="toggle(this)" /></th>
<?php foreach($fields as $field_name => $field_display):?>
<th><?php echo $field_display ?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot class="table_header">
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" name="check_all" id="master_box" onclick="toggle(this)" /></th>
<?php foreach($fields as $field_name => $field_display):?>
<th><?php echo $field_display ?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
<?php foreach($categories as $cat):?>
<tr>
<td><input id="sec_id"name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat->sec_id; ?>" /></td>
<td><?php echo $cat->category; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $cat->description; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $cat->slug; ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>

</table>

</div>
```

If you notice there is an empty  tag.It is meant to display the number of articles in the category(section).

How do get the number of articles associated with each category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.sec_id,s.category,s.slug,s.description,COUNT(a.id) FROM sections s 
    LEFT JOIN articale a ON s.sec_id = a.section_id 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY s.sec_id 
ORDER BY s.category ASC
```

Comment: thanks it worked i just modified the count(a.id) to count(a.id) as articles